# python - Using a variable as part of a class method/function

Tags: python, syntax

I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I'm an amateur so here i am.

Trying to use the [obd](https://github.com/brendan-w/python-OBD) python library to communicate with my vehicle. I have a bluetooth OBDII adapter and on it's own i can send single commands as outlined in the basic usage section of the readme and get responses.

My problem is that i have a list of commands that i want to send. I'm trying to use a for loop to go through each command and print the responses on screen.

```
import os
import time
import obd

def clear_Screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


connection = obd.OBD("COM7")
pids = [ 'RPM' , 'ENGINE_LOAD' , 'COOLANT_TEMP' , 'RUN_TIME' ]

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        clear_Screen()
        for i in pids:
            cmd = "obd.commands." + i
            response = connection.query(cmd)
            print i , ": " , (response.value)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

there's a problem with how I'm building the cmd variable because the response i get from each query is that the command isn't supported but i know they are.

if i print cmd instead of trying to use the command.query(cmd) it prints exactly like it would be if i specified it i.e. obd.commands.RPM so I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, in your code you write _connection_.query(cmd) while in the elaboration of your question you mention _command_.query(cmd) so, could it be one of them is faulty? Or do you mean the same thing? I am unfamiliar with OBD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you stated:

> there's a problem with how I'm building the cmd variable

Indeed, in your way, cmd is only a string. So instead if you want the actual evaluated attitude, you should use `getattr` instead:

```
cmd = getattr(obd.commands,i)
```

`eval()` and `exec()` are both unsafe so you should never use those.

Comment: Thank you sir, this solved it... Would you mind explaining to a layperson what the difference of using 'only a string' and the 'actual evaluated attitude' is?

Comment: When I said only a string here's what I mean: if you `print(type(cmd))` from your original example it will show `<class 'str'>`. Which means that it's a string. While if you used the cmd in my example and do the same thing, it should show something like `<class 'obd.OBDCommand.OBDCommand'>`. As you can see, they are very different kind of objects. Mine is the one you wanted because it's an actual custom-made object. While strings are just some plain text.

Comment: When I said "actual evaluated attitude", I meant that cmd isn't a string anymore(with the text `"obd.commands.RPM"`), but instead, what `obd.commands.RPM` actually is. Since you're combining `obd.commands` with `RPM` to form something, doing it using `"obd.commands." + "RPM"` wouldn't work because it's technically translated to `str + str` which always make another `str`. Therefor you were creating another string that was assigned to cmd. Using `getattr` is a Python way of doing this correctly and not to produce a string, it literally means `get attribute`.

Comment: makes sense. I'm still learning about how attributes come into play in situations like this. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Try wrapping what you're assigning to cmd in `eval()`:

```
cmd = eval("obd.commands." + i)
```

Comment: Although this works, you are advised to never use eval like this because it's a security loophole

Comment: Oh fair enough, I didn't know that.

Comment: By the way, I'm not the one who downvoted, almost every answer involving this method get downvoted by someone.